# Angular 2 Router error, Route config should contain exactly one "component", "loader", or "redirectTo" property

Tags: angular

This is my setup:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {LocationStrategy, APP_BASE_HREF, HashLocationStrategy, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HomeComponent} from "../components/HomeComponent";
import {provide} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<a [routerLink]="['/Home']">Home</a>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', component: HomeComponent, name: 'HomeComponent' }
])
class RootComponent {
    constructor(router:Router) {

    }
}

bootstrap(RootComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
    , provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'})]);
```

and I keep getting this error,
any help is appreciated

[image]

I am using latest Beta.0

regards

Sean

Comment: What do you get when you log HomeComponent? Is it defined?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. you were right, I had a bug in export of HomeComponent... that fixed it!! TX!!!! let me ask you, how did you know? this is the biggest issue I am having with ng2, is that the errors are VERY cryptic. I am coming for Backbone.js world, which is super easy, errors are always per the line of issue, and there are no transpilers. rrrrrrrrr

Comment: I ran into this too. The issue I encountered was with the routed component being on the same page. If it is, then the error above will be thrown. The component that is being routed too must be imported. Which is most likely a bug with the beta version. Hopefully the error reporting gets better for the router with time.

Answer (score 2):

I had met same issue,but I resolved by using the same component name used in the component definition and when import the component,eg:

> definition

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'register-page',
    template: `
        <h4>Register</h4>

    `
})
export class RegisterPageComponent {
   //public hero: Hero;
}
```

> import

```
import {RegisterPageComponent} from './register.component';

@RouteConfig([
   {path: '/register',   name: 'Register',component: RegisterPageComponent}
])
```

I met the same issue when I tried to change the component name on import eg: issue

```
import {RegisterComponent} from './register.component'; 

/*remove`Page` from the name ,it should be RegisterPageComponent*/
```

> route

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/register',name:'Register',component:RegisterComponent}
])
```

Comment: your component name is `RegisterPageComponent` then how it will work with component in RouteConfig named as `component:RegisterComponent` ?

Comment: @PardeepJain i mentioned that we cant change the component name from definition and at the time of import, and i'm showing that, that will make an error,
   
import {RegisterComponent} from './register.component'; 

(we changed component name from definition and we mentioning the component in the route)

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/register',name:'Register',component:RegisterComponent}
])

Comment: yes i think its obvious and its compulsory for routing to have same name in the component export class and routeconfig component. i dont think this is something new for the answer don't   you think so ?

Comment: @PardeepJain I don't know much, I met the issue, and resolved like what I said :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My import was not surrounded by curly braces, so it was undefined.
The problem is the cryptic error message, which should state that the component you provided is `undefined` for the `@RouteConfig`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but for an other reason. It's true that the error reporting is still very poor in ng2. The error: Route config should contain exactly one “component”, “loader”, or “redirectTo” property, really just means that what you have put in your routeConfig is not correct. In my case, my components were undefined. This due to a stupid order mistake.

I had this (component.ts)

```
export * from './trackerpanel.component';
export * from './login.component';
export * from './oauthcallback.component';
export * from './tracker.component';
export * from './settings.component';
```

And an import like this (trackerpanel.component)

```
import {TrackerComponent, SettingsComponent} from './component';
```

And I was trying to use the components tracker and settings in routes defined in trackerpanel. This gave me undefined components, and the aforementioned error.

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', name: 'Tracker', component: TrackerComponent, useAsDefault: true },
  {path: '/settings', name: 'Settings', component: SettingsComponent }
])
```

I changed it to

```
export * from './tracker.component';
export * from './settings.component';
export * from './trackerpanel.component';
export * from './login.component';
export * from './oauthcallback.component';
```

And this fixed my routing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same error i had faced but i have solved this as below:

when i write the code like this

```
{ path: '/formDemo', Component: FormDemo, name: "FormDemo"},
```

it shows throws the same error you faced but after searching i have found error is in my `Component` attribute of routeConfig i.e angular2 thinks we have write a Component annotation in the routeConfig but it accept only exactly one loader,component,redirectto (URL) property. but we have write something else , so when i changed `Component` with `component` code is working fine.

```
{ path: '/formDemo', component: FormDemo, name: "FormDemo"},
```

above  line make my code working. 
It may not help to solve your problem because you have already write component insted of Component but i have posted this for others may be it will help to someone else thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was incorrectly imported child component. The component export was default:

```
export default class HomeComponent {}
```

So i replaced its import from

```
import { HomeComponent } from './homeComponent';
```

to

```
import HomeComponent from './homeComponent';
```

and it works!

Interesting that webpack which i use to bundle the app does not provide any errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the mismatch of the component name in import {TestComponent}
and "export class TestingComponent"

TestingComponent should be TestComponent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now.
This had to do with me creating a component, and Webpack didn't recognize it.

After restarting Webpack the error went away..

Answer (score 0):

Your NgModule should be changed from

```
provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
    , provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'})]);
```

To

```
providers: [LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}), {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}]
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12295