# Angular2 router with child-router not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get my child-router to work.
The goal is to make a sort of navigation-bar like in this [website](https://discordapp.com/channels/@me). So we have a router which contains all the main tabs, and each tab has his own routers that navigate to its corresponding view or component.

Yet I get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterLink -> Router).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Route config should contain exactly one "component", "loader", or "redirectTo" property.
```

[image: stacktrace error]

**/app/game/organisation/organisation-list.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';
import {Theme} from "../theme/theme";
import {Router,RouteParams} from "angular2/router";
import {OrganisationService} from "./organisation.service";
import {Organisation} from "./organisation";
import {OrganisationComponent} from "./organisation.component";
import {ThemeComponent} from "../theme/theme.component";

@Component({
    template: `
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#organisation of organisations">
       <a [routerLink]="['OrganisationList','Organisation',{organisationId: organisation.organisationId}]">Organisation naam</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
    directives: [RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/:organisationId/theme/...', name: 'Organisation', component: OrganisationComponent},
    //   {path: '/:organisationId/theme/...', name: 'Theme', component: ThemeComponent},
])

export class OrganisationListComponent {
    public organisations:Organisation[];

    constructor(private routeParams:RouteParams,
                private router:Router,
                private organisationService:OrganisationService) {
        this.organisationService.getOrganisations().subscribe((organisations:Organisation[])=> {
            this.organisations = organisations;
        });
    }
}
```

**/app/app.component.ts**

```
/**
 * Created by J.P on 26/02/2016.
 */
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {CardListComponent} from "./game/card/card-list.component";
import {NewThemeComponent} from "./game/theme/new-theme.component";
import {CardService} from "./game/card/card.service";
import {CircleComponent} from "./game/circle/circle.component";
import {ThemeService} from "./game/theme/theme.service";
import {OrganisationService} from "./game/organisation/organisation.service";
import {Organisation} from "./game/organisation/organisation";
import {Router} from "angular2/router";
import {OrganisationComponent} from "./game/organisation/organisation.component";
import {ThemeComponent} from "./game/theme/theme.component";
import {OrganisationListComponent} from "./game/organisation/organisation-list.component";
import {LandingPageComponent} from "./game/landing-page.component";
import {UserService} from "./game/user/user.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <a  [routerLink]="['CardList']">CardList </a> |
    <a  [routerLink]="['Circle']">Circle 1 </a> |
    <a  [routerLink]="['Theme']">Create Theme</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers:[CardService,ThemeService,OrganisationService,UserService]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', redirectTo:['/LandingPage']},
    {path: '/landing', name: 'LandingPage', component: LandingPageComponent, useAsDefault: true},
   // {path: '/organisation', name: 'Home', component: AppComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/organisation/...', name: 'OrganisationList', component: OrganisationListComponent},
    {path: '/card-list', name:'CardList', component:CardListComponent},
    {path: '/circle/1', name:'Circle', component:CircleComponent},
    {path: '/theme', name:'Theme', component:NewThemeComponent}
])
export class AppComponent{


}
```

Also about the documentation found on the latest versions of Angular2 a lot of things aren't explained like the childs for example `{path: '/parent/...', name: 'Parent', component: ParentComponent}`

Comment: How did you fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points i have to tell here too Long for comment so posting as answer.

1. No need to provide `RouterOutlet` in the list of directives as you did in the question. because according to officials `RouterLink` and `router-outlet` and included when we inject `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` in the list of directives.
2. Here is explanation about child routing, you are looking for.
   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html
   (in the routing and navigation section.)
3. Same error i had faced but i have solved this as below:

when i write the code like this

```
{ path: '/formDemo', Component: FormDemo, name: "FormDemo"}
```

it shows throws the same error you faced but after searching i have found error is in my Component attribute of routeConfig i.e angular2 thinks we have write a Component annotation in the routeConfig but it accept only exactly one loader,component,redirectto (URL) property. but we have write something else , so when i changed Component with component code is working fine.

```
{ path: '/formDemo', component: FormDemo, name: "FormDemo"}
```

above line make my code working. It may not help to solve your problem because you have already write component insted of Component but i have posted this for others may be it will help to someone else thanks.

same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/34349420/5043867